# CryptUIWizImport and protection password

Tags: winapi, certificate

I need to programmatically import certificate into Windows store.
The CryptUIWizImport function works well but Windows asks user create additional password to protect the certificate.
But user can choose to not set this password.

Is it possible to avoid Windows UI and set this additional password programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

As the following code you should empty the password field:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "windows.h"
#include "Cryptuiapi.h"

#pragma comment(lib, "Cryptui.lib")

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]){
    CRYPTUI_WIZ_IMPORT_SRC_INFO importSrc;    
    memset(&importSrc, 0, sizeof(CRYPTUI_WIZ_IMPORT_SRC_INFO));    
    importSrc.dwSize = sizeof(CRYPTUI_WIZ_IMPORT_SRC_INFO);    
    importSrc.dwSubjectChoice = CRYPTUI_WIZ_IMPORT_SUBJECT_FILE;    
    importSrc.pwszFileName = L"C:\\PathToPFX\\cert.pfx";    
    importSrc.pwszPassword = L"";    
    importSrc.dwFlags = CRYPT_EXPORTABLE | CRYPT_USER_PROTECTED;             
    if (CryptUIWizImport(    
      CRYPTUI_WIZ_NO_UI,    
      NULL,    
      NULL,    
      &importSrc,    
      NULL    
    ) == 0)    
    {    
      printf(“CryptUIWizImport error 0x%x\n”, GetLastError());    
    }
    return 0;
}
```